# Unhide grouped columns with win32.com in Python

Tags: python, excel, winapi

Several columns of excel documents have been grouped and hidden.

How to use win32.com to expand them?

```
excel_path = str(Path.cwd() / 'data.xlsx')
excel = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excel_path)
wb.RefreshAll()#refresh data from external source
excel.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
excel.DisplayAlerts = False

ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
ws.Outline.ShowLevels(ColumnLevels=1)# Try to expand all columns in worksheet, is this correct?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
ws.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden=False
```